# Using Yahoo Pipes and loops

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I have a feed from Google Books that lists some books I have. I want to create a new feed that has the Books' prices (as used books, going to feed it to a next service to get the prices). Yahoo pipes loop module does not allow operator modules or user input modules.

How can iterate though the Google Books' Feed items so that I can use it for a next service say a Fetch Page Module ?

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo pipes are not the recommended way to go forward. Yahoo itself has replaced it with [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) and that's where all the innovation is. Look specifically at community tables and at Execute statements, it might be relevant.

Comment: Cool where did you hear that Yahoo Pipes was replaced with YQL? I use YQL statements within Yahoo Pipes currently.

Comment: Hmm. I heard it directly from Yahoo at Yahoo's New York Hack Day (two days including a hack night - awesome). At the time they said that Pipes were going away and YQL will be the way forward.

But that was a while ago. I just did a search and can see the mention of Pipe 2, now powered by YQL. I guess people still prefer visual interface and they changed their opinions. My bad, should have double checked the references first. 
http://blog.pipes.yahoo.net/2010/06/09/yahoo-pipes-v2-engine/

Let's hope somebody else can help with the pipe syntax then.

Answer (score 1):

You can put one of your pipes inside the loop operator, acting as a subpipe.